# Uploading form Data in post API in angular 5 but It is giving body like this [object FormData]

Tags: javascript, angular5, multipartform-data

this is my TS file code and screen shot when I hit API,I am uploading multiple images and want to send those images as an array
API is giving 400 http error as my back end requires Form Data 
[image]

```
decentralizationFormSubmit(value){
console.log('value',value);
let headingarr=[];
headingarr.push(value.widget_main_heading1);
headingarr.push(value.widget_main_heading2);
headingarr.push(value.widget_main_heading3);
let widgetContentarr=[];
widgetContentarr.push(value.widget_content1);
widgetContentarr.push(value.widget_content2);
widgetContentarr.push(value.widget_content3);
let imageArr=[]
imageArr.push(this.file1)
imageArr.push(this.file2)
imageArr.push(this.file3)
console.log('imageArr',imageArr);

var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < imageArr.length; i++) { 
  formData.append("multipartFiles",imageArr[i],imageArr[i].name);
}
var formData1=new FormData();
let obj={
  mainHeading:value.main_head,
  subHeading:value.sub_head,
  imageMainHeading:headingarr,
  imageContent:widgetContentarr,
  multipartFiles:JSON.stringify(formData)
}
for(let key in obj){
  formData1.append(key,obj[key])
}
console.log('FormaDAta',JSON.stringify(formData1));
this.heroService.decentralizationSubmission(formData1).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  console.log('res',res);
})
```

}

Comment: Feel free:
- to read the documentation on FormData#append: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
- to try to understand what it means to send a form as multipart/form-data
- to respect yourself and others that will read your code (indentation, variable names...)

FormData is not JSON. Even though you could encode some part as JSON string.  
What will never work here is:
- first the imbrication of formData in formData1 (make an effort on the naming here)
- second the JSON serialization of formData

Comment: I spend days trying to figure out how to upload a picture to the Google Photos API using formdata. The API returned and uploaded token, but the photo did not exist. When I changed the body of my post from "formdata" to the file object, it worked perfectly.